# Automatically repeating failing cypress tests on bamboo

Tags: continuous-integration, automated-tests, bamboo, cypress

We have a CI system bamboo which runs several jobs of logically divided cypress tests. Cypress is a good tool to write tests but as with front-end test automation in some cases it is impossible to make the tests 100% non-flaky. So they can fail in the first run but when re-run they pass (or vice-versa).

We in the company want to link our software's build to the result of cypress tests i.e. if the cypress test job fails the build of the software will fail as well.

My question is quite simple, is there a way to re-run failed tests on bamboo automatically before bamboo finally marks the cypress test job as failed?

Comment: I know this is not what you are asking, but it should be possible to get your Cypress tests working 100% every run (i.e non-flakiness). Cypress has some features for this, like **auto-retry in commands** but it sometimes need some wrangling to get working perfectly. I doubt that retrying the whole Cypress suite is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @eric99 I did not mean to retry the entire cypress suite instead only repeating failing cypress tests within a suite, which does not cause the bamboo job to fail if the repeated test pass. Also which auto-retry commands are you talking about in cypress?

Comment: @eric99 On a predictable app that may be entirely true. The app I'm testing is almost completely asynchronous, so I can't rely on the DOM, and it polls regularly for state updates instead of processing locally. When I do something, I don't get the result immediately, and there is no way to know for certain when an update has occured and been processed. I realize this is a special case, but I believe there are some special cases where Cypress' idea of complete non-flakiness doesn't work all the time. We use Bamboo and so I would be very interested in seeing if this is possible.

Comment: @ITguy Most if not all Cypress commands will continually retry until they time out as defined in the config. For example, if you do a `.get()` and the element it's looking for doesn't exist, it will keep trying for a default of about 5 seconds before throwing an error.

Comment: @JoshuaWade, that does not sound like a special scenario - nearly every javascript app has some async component. The times where I have been caught out by Cypress is where I am selecting for **structure** which is present from the initial page load, when I should have been selecting for **content** which is the bit that gets loaded asynchronously - e.g use `cy.contains('div.myClass', 'myAsyncContent', {timeout: 10000})` to wait for **up to** 10 seconds (will succeed earlier if possible).

Comment: So, in summary I think it is worth putting the effort into finding out why particular Cypress tests might be flaky, as it most likely indicates a flaw in the test design.

Comment: @eric99 the scenario that I face is that sometimes there might be that some data is not properly loaded from the db, but re-running makes it ok. Secondly sometimes the page does not load properly and some elements might be missing for whatever reason, causes the test to fail. This happens alot that a test fails on bamboo build but when I re-run the test locally I cannot reproduce the error and it runs fine on bamboo too. There is a feature request for cypress hopefully we will see it soon https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1313

Comment: You should check out this repo that one of the Cypress devs has posted around this. https://gist.github.com/Bkucera/4ffd05f67034176a00518df251e19f58 Found while also hoping to figure out a mechanism to weed out flak prone tests while in ci. The cypress issue thread is : https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1313